# JOIN statement not working with where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to do

```
select * 
from buildings 
where levels = 3 
join managers;
```

but it says error at join. I want to match the the id of the building with the id in the managers table so I think I want natural join.

Comment: That's because the syntax is wrong. 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp`

Comment: Is inner join what SQL calls natural join in relational algebra? I thought join automatically joined at the attribute with the same name in the two tables.

Comment: @LewsTherin: Please don't link to http://w3fools.com/, they're a bad source of information that has gamed Google's rankings to get to the top. The [PostgreSQL docs on SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) would be a much better reference in this case.

Comment: @muistooshort Reminds me, in your travels have you come across a HTML-ized public version of any of the SQL standards that's a good link target? Like the Pg docs, but DBMS independent?

Comment: @CraigRinger: Unfortunately no. But I haven't looked that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the JOIN in the right place (between FROM and WHERE) and it were legal to write JOIN without ON then the result would be a cross join - a cartesian product that you then filter in WHERE.

That's a perfectly valid thing to do, though not probably what you intended in this case. It can be achieved by adding comma-separate tables to the `FROM` clause, eg:

```
FROM buildings, managers
```

It's generally better style to write an *explicit inner join* when you intend to join two tables on a condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM buildings b INNER JOIN managers m ON (b.manager_id = m.manager_id)
WHERE b.levels = 3;
```

... because it makes it clear to someone else reading the statement that the `ON` clause is a join condition, and the `bl.levels=3` is a filter. The SQL implementation generally doesn't care, and quite likely transforms the above into:

```
SELECT *
FROM buildings b, managers m
WHERE b.levels = 3 AND b.manager_id = m.manager_id;
```

internally anyway, but it's easier (IMO) to understand complex queries with many joins when they're written using explicit join syntax.

There's another way to write what you want, but it's dangerous and IMO shouldn't be used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM buildings bl
NATURAL JOIN managers m                                      
WHERE bl.levels = 3;
```

That JOINs on any columns that're named the same. It's a nightmare to debug, you have to look up the table structures to understand what it does, it breaks if someone renames a column, and it's just painful. Do not use. See [Table expressions in the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

More acceptable is the `USING` syntax also discussed above:

```
SELECT * 
FROM buildings bl
INNER JOIN managers m USING (manager_id)
WHERE bl.levels = 3;
```

which matches the columns named `manager_id` in both columns and `JOIN`s on them, combining them into a single column, but unlike `NATURAL JOIN` does so explicitly and without scary magic.

I still prefer to write `INNER JOIN ... ON (...)` but it's reasonable to use `USING` and, IMO, never reasonable to use `NATURAL`.

---

Test table structures were:

```
create table managers ( manager_id integer primary key );

create table buildings (
    manager_id integer references manager(manager_id),
    levels integer
);
```

Comment: Hooray for explicit JOINs! That's usually the only way to do an OUTER  JOIN anyway (unless, AFAIK, you're using Sybase or one of its derivatives and have `*=`).

Comment: @muistooshort Oracle has/had crazy join syntax too. They used, among other things, `(+)` to mean "By the way, the join for this table I'm mentioning in the `WHERE` clause is an outer join, not that I told you than in the `FROM` clause". ANSI joins only appeared in 9i, they stuck to their own odd syntax before then. See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187, http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` operator applied to the tables, you should provide it in the `FROM` clause. If you do so you will get a new error claiming that there is no `JOIN` condition, because you have to provide the `JOIN` condition after the `ON` clause (it is not optional):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  buildings b JOIN managers m ON b.managerid = m.id
WHERE b.levels = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do that, you have to write something like:

```
select * 
from bulidings b
join managers m on b.id=m.id
where levels = 3
```

The request seems odd however, I believe that one of them should have a foreign key into the other. So a more appropriate query would be:

```
select *
from buidings b
join managers m on b.id = m.building_id //// or b.manager_id = m.id
where levels = 3
```

Answer (score -1):

I think which query you are written is wrong.

So please try this

```
 select * from buildings as bl
    join managers as mn on bl.F_ManagerID = mn.ManagerID
    where bl.levels = 3
```

I think this will help you...

Comment: This is wrong too - did you try it? There is no `==` operator, and you meant `dl.F_ManagerID` not `bl.F_ManagerID`. IMO it's more clearly written as `INNER JOIN ... ON` anyway.